# MQTT Azure IOT Hub Connection C#

Tags: c#, azure

I am trying to create secure TCP Client and trying to connect with Microsoft Azure IOT hub over port number 8883 i.e. MQTT Protocol. I have created connect packet for azure IOT hub with below Packet Format. Everytime SSLStream.read returns 0 in my case. Checked with OpenSSL whether connection with iot hub with certificate on port number 8883 is working or not, with Open SSL it is working.
What is wrong in my packet or code which fails my connection ?

```
TcpClient client = new TcpClient(machineName,8883);
            Console.WriteLine("Client connected.");
            // Create an SSL stream that will close the client's stream.
            SslStream sslStream = new SslStream(
                client.GetStream(),
                false,
                new RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(ValidateServerCertificate),
                null
                );

Connect Packet :
    0x10 - Connect,Remaining Length,Protocol Length,'M','Q','I','S','D','P',Level,Flag,Keep Alive,Client Id Length,Client ID, User Name Length,User Name,Password Length,Password
```